# How can I pass an array to email template and then use them in email template?

Tags: email

How can I pass an array to email template and then use them in email template ?

Comment: What version of Magento are you talking about

Answer (score -1):

> **Disclaimer**: Make Google search is a practice before throw a question here.

Suppose you are passing an array into an email template as shown below:

```
<?php
$templateArray = array(
    'key'        => 'value',
    'anotherkey' => 'another value'
);
$mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
    'myarray' => $templateArray
));
```

Now you can access this in the email template like this.

```
myarray.key           //result: value
myarray.anotherkey    //result: another value
```

Comment: This is not working.